# Guava: Does awaitRunning() method guarantee that runOneIteration() is called before returning?

Tags: java, guava

I need to start a service which extends the service [`AbstractScheduledService`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html) in Guava. I want to start the service in such a way that [`runOneIteration()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html#runOneIteration--) method is executed as soon as the service is started by running it's start method.

I don't want to use [`startAsync()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html#startAsync--) method as that would return asynchronously.

If I use [`awaitRunning()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html#awaitRunning--), the documentation specifies that it will only return after the service reaches **RUNNING** state. But does that guarantee that `runOneIteration()` is called before returning? If not, is there any way I can guarantee that `runOneIteration()` is called at least once before returning from starting the service.

Here is one approach:

1. If I Override the [`startUp()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html#startUp--) method and call `runOneIteration()` in it, is this going to work?

   ```
   @Override
   public void startUp() {
   runOneIteration();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a dirty hack I used to solve this issue.

```
public void start() {
  runOneIteration();
  startAsync();
}

@Override
protected Scheduler scheduler() {
    return Scheduler.newFixedRateSchedule(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

I call the `start()` method on this service.

```
serviceName.start();
```

This ensures that `runOneIteration` is executed once when `serviceName.start()` is called.